Auto-zero op-amp design
I am trying to design an Auto-Zero op-amp for a school project.
I found the circuit below in a paper released by Texas Instruments and I am trying to replicate this, but I can't understand what "-Bn" and "+Bm" are.
I first thought that it was another differential pair inside the op-amp, but I couldn't find any op-amp design with two differential inputs.
I asked someone at my school what they were and he said that I should connect those wires to the inverting input of the amplifiers, but that didn't sound right.
So I am asking what are those inputs, should I make modifications to my op-amp? (I am using a folded cascode with a class AB output stage.)
The link to the TI paper is: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt204/slyt204.pdf


This is a fine project as described.  However, if you are still shopping around for ideas, consider a microcontroller solution where you can acquire the signal with an ADC, do the offset digitally, and output the result with a DAC.  This shifts effort away from a strictly analog design to a mixed design of analog, digital, and programming (...more baskets, more fun!).  Oh, now I've noticed your username.  Nevermind.

The paper refers to "additional inputs" to the op-amps.
So consider \$A_M\$ to have two non-inverting inputs and \$A_N\$ to have two inverting inputs. The numbers \$A_M\$ and  \$A_N\$  also refer to the magnitude of the open-loop differential gain of the respective amplifiers from the normal inverting and non-inverting inputs.
The numbers \$B_M\$ and \$B_N\$ refer to the magnitude of the open-loop gain from those "extra" inputs.
How you might implement those "special" op-amps is another question.. summing two op-amps with one of the inputs of one op-amp grounded might be one way.
